# How to list changes in a specific folder using Google Drive API Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am using the Changes:list API to list changes.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/list

But the results include all the folders in my drive. I want to filter the results for a specific folder. In the documentation, I don't see a parameter "q" for "changes:list" like the "Files:List"  has.

Is there a way to filter the results via API parameter? or Do I need to do it in my code using the "folder Id" that I already know?

This is the code that I am using:

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.changes.list({
        //The collection works by providing the current state of each item, if and only if the item has changed since a given point in time.
        //point in history to retrive changes, we can saved this to know if there are changes
        pageToken: '820167',

        
        //test parameters that are not working
        //q: "'12pDb31bRw7p3pfJoF_N6VncDqISSY1W4' in parents",
        //q: 'trashed=false and "'+ folderId +'" in parents',

        fields: '*',
        pageSize:  5,
        orderby:'title',
        maxResults: 50
      });

      request.execute(function (resp) {
        console.log(resp);
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might suggest instead using the [Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2), which will let you query for changes within a folder. You'll want to specify the parameter `ancestorName=items/${folderId}`. Drive Activity will also give you a much more in-depth view of the actual activity that took place.

The Drive changes resource is pretty minimal. It is designed to provide a very quick view of changes across an entire drive / shared drive. The value it adds is the ability to setup a watch for push notifications - these could be used to trigger further action.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you want cannot be achieved as the `Changes: list` method returns **the list of changes for a user or shared drive.**

Therefore, if you want to retrieve the changes for a specific folder, you will have to filter them afterwards programmatically in your code.

You can also submit a **feature request** on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106) and provide all the necessary details.

#### Reference

- [Drive API v3 Changes:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/list).